# Discrete maths proof method

Tags: discrete-mathematics, real-numbers

Prove that at least one of the real numbers $x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n$ is greater than or equal to the average of these
numbers.

Comment: Reading the title, I expected something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say all of the numbers $x_1,x_2,x_3, \cdots ,x_n$ are strictly less than the average $\bar x=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$.

Then we have that $$x_1 < \bar x$$
$$x_2 < \bar x$$
$$x_3 < \bar x$$
$$.$$ $$.$$ $$.$$
$$x_n < \bar x$$

Adding the inequalities, we get that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i<n \bar x$$ or $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i<\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$$

CONTRADICTION.

Answer (score 1):

Without Loss Of Generality let $x_1\le x_2\le \cdots{}\le x_n$. Now it suffices to show that

\begin{align*}
x_n \ge{} \dfrac{x_1+x_2+\cdots{}+x_n}{n}
&\implies{}nx_n\ge x_1+x_2+\cdots{}+x_n \\
&\implies{}(x_n-x_1)+(x_n-x_2)+\cdots{}+(x_n-x_n)\ge{}0
\end{align*}

which clearly holds as $x_n\ge{}x_j$ where $1\le{j}\le{}n$. Equality holds if $x_1=x_2=\cdots{}=x_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose not, i.e. the inequalities $x_j < \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ holds for $j = 1, \dots, n$. Adding them we get $$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i < \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$ a contradiction.